# Concatenation and proportion in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

A little background:
I have two tables imported from excel. One is 300k + rows so when I do updates to it in excel it just runs too slow, and often doesn't process on my comp.  Anyways, I used a 'outer' left join to bring the two together.
Now when I run the query, I get the result which works fine but I need to add some fields to these results.

I am hoping to mimic what Ive done in excel, so I can create my summary pivots in the same manner.

First, I need a field that just concatenates two others after the join.

Then I need to add a field the equivalent of:
`1/Countif($T$2:$T$3330,T2)` from excel to access.  However, the range does not need to be fixed.  I will get it so that all the text entries are at the top of the field, so in theory, i need the equivalent of `Sheets("").Range("T2").End(xldown)`. This proportion is used to eliminate double counting when i do pivot tables.

I am probably making this much more complicated than it has to be but I am new to Access as well, so please try to explain some things in explanations.

Thanks

Edit: I currently have:

```
    Select [Table1].*, [Table2].PlaySk, [Table2].Service
    From [Table1] Left Join [Table2] On [Table1].Play + [Table1].Skill 
    = [Table2].PlaySk
```

And in a general case, what I am trying to solve is something to get ColAB and ColProportion.

```
ColA      ColB       ColAB        ColProportion
a          1          a1              .5
b          1          b1              1
a          1          a1              .5
b          2          b2              .3333333
b          2          b2              .3333333
b          2          b2              .3333333
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you'll need to make a couple queries in sequence to do everything you need.

The first part (concatenate) is relatively easy though -- just take the two field names you wish to concatenate together, say [Play] and [Skill], and, in design view, make a new field like "PlaySk: [Play] & [Skill]".

If you want to put a character between them (I often do when I concatenate, just to keep things straight), like a semicolon for example, you can do "PlaySk: [Play] & ';' & [Skill]".

As for the second part, I think you'll want to build a "Group By" query on top of the other one. In your original query, make another field in design view like this: "T2_Counter: Iif([The field you're checking, i.e. whatever column T is] = 'whatever value you're checking for, i.e. whatever T2 is',1,0)". This will result in a column that's a 1 when the check is true, and a zero otherwise.

Then bring this query into a new one, click "Totals" at the top in the Design tab, then bring the fields you want to group by down. Then create a field in design view like this: "MagicField: 1/Sum(T2_Counter)".

Hopefully this helps get you started at least.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  With the countif equivalent, will it change the checking value?

Comment: I made some edits to the original with an example.  See how the proportion is going to be reliant on the value directly to the left of it?

Comment: @user3697498 The T2_Counter would not affect the values it's checking, that's why you create a separate field off to the side that doesn't affect your original data. I see your edits above, but am still having a hard time visualizing the problem. Can you please post a couple sample records from Table1 and Table2 (including all relevant field names), and then show us what you want your final output to look like?